# How to Integrate Unity with Google Play Game Services for iPhone and Android games

Tags: android, unity, ios, google-play

I want to integrate Google Play Game Services for Apple's iOS and for Android.
How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a plugin to do that. I've used this one and it was straightforward to set up and use (works for both iOS and Android):

https://github.com/faizann/UnityGPGPlugin

Some things to keep in mind (because the debugging log messages shown won't help you understand what really happens, all of them reporting that the application w/ the given key was not found on the server):

- When sending your .apk over to Google, enter the SHA-1 from your
  certificate manually (extract your certificate from the .apk and run the keytool on it). Sometimes Google screws up automatically doing
  this and the services won't work afterwards.
- Be sure to log in with a preset test account when testing
  (obviously).

Comment: Thanks Alex M, 
Will it work flawlessly?

Comment: It worked for me.